# how to run youtube-local python website on replit and access it on other devices as a website

Tags: python, flask, youtube-api, replit

i am trying to create a repl on replit.com from last 3 months

for the youtube front-end youtube-local

youtube-local github:

https://github.com/user234683/youtube-local

which is created in python

i want this repl to host the youtube-local as a website that i can access from my other devices for the

replacement of normal youtube website.

i hope that someone can make this repl happen up perfectly

that it can host a youtube-local instance website that can be accessed out on the web-browser of other devices

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.